# Why have users lost their access to App Script projects? And why cannot it be shared?

Tags: google-apps-script

Latest weeks users have lost their access to several App Script Projects which they had access to before and still should have because they are listed when you press "Share Sheet + Script". The file has not been moved and the map the files are included in is also shared with the users. They get the message that the page cannot be found / cannot be opened right now when they try to enter.

Before the App Script file had a Share button which now is gone and when using the legacy editor and press share I get a message that "An error occurred. The selected file cannot be shared at this time"

Thankful for any help!
/Fredrik

Comment: I sounds like it might be due to recent improvements in security which involve the sharing of files.  Perhaps you should check with you admin.

Comment: Is there any specific improvements regarding this i can check? I am the owner/admin of these scripts.

Comment: Honestly I just got a couple emails from google regarding such things but since I don't have any users in my account it did not affect me so I didn't pay much attention to them.